# Unable to connect to MySQL from Java Servlet in Amazon EC2

Tags: mysql, tomcat, amazon-ec2, connector-j

I recently deployed a `.war` from `Netbeans IDE` on my local machine to `Amazon EC2`. The Servlet in my Webapp used JBDC `Connector/J`, the jar file for which was copied into Libraries in Netbeans. The WebApp was working well on my local machine. But the logs of Tomcat on Amazon EC2 shows an error `the host 'xyz' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL Server`.

Comment: Where is the MySQL server located? Amazon or local? If on Amazon, do the security group and the instance firewall (if applicable) allow access to your EC2 Tomcat instance?

Comment: @Viccari MySQL is located on the Amazon server. Does local access to MySQL from Servlet require opening port 3306 in Security group?

Comment: If both Tomcat and MySQL are on the same EC2 instance, I don't think so. Are they?

Comment: @Viccari Yes, they are on same Amazon EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

confirm host information for mysql - run this on mysql:

```
select host, user from mysql.user;
```

If your host/port information is correct, try checking privileges being used for the web application.  Also, make sure that your database server is able to bind on the specified port (netstat -an | grep 'port number') & that the client app can connect to that port (on the host).  hope it helps

Comment: I am totally new to this. I run the command you suggested and it gives a table with `host/user` name. All the users are `root`. I cannot do anything else you suggested. Can you help with little more details? Thanks.

Comment: is your client app able to bind to any local port - use any test socket application, run it on a specific port (not the one on which mysql is listening on). If it is unable to do so, e.g port 1999 (throws exception/you do not see it in the netstat -an | grep 1999), then you should be checking your VM security group (i.e. add that port to the security group).  After adding to the security group, reboot the VM and try again till your test socket server is able to bind.  If this works, try the same for your mysql client (open port on security group, reboot instance and try again).